# $wp_query->queried_object->ID throws warning: Undefined property

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, wp-query

```
<?php 
    $current_term = $wp_query->queried_object->name;
    $current_term_id = $wp_query->queried_object->ID;
?>

<hgroup class="section-heading wrapper">
    <h1><?php echo $current_term; ?></h1>
    <h3><?php echo category_description( $current_term_id ); ?></h3>
</hgroup>
```

This works fine but the `$current_term_id` variable throws a warning …

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$ID in /Users/my/htdocs/wr/wp-content/themes/wr/taxonomy-event_type.php on line 12
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here or what's the real property for the ID of the current term?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I faced the exact same problem for days and then found this!
Use the function `$wp_query->get_queried_object_id()`. Check [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

There's also a wrapper for this function [`get_queried_object_id()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_queried_object_id/). It calls all parts like `global $wp_query` by itself.

### API

> Always use the most low level API, until you're forced to do otherwise.

The definition of API by the (current) wikipedia article is like the following

> An application programming interface (API) is a specification intended to be used as an interface by software components to communicate with each other.

This means, that it was written to communicate with **core internals** and your **theme** or **plugin**.

### Why?

Because of one easy reason: A wrapping API allows cores **internals** to transform, while still staying compatible with whatever you throw in as arguments. A wrapper function can add backwards compatibility where a core class/object may not.

It also shortens your code, makes it more readable and allows you to focus on what needs to be done by your code.

Answer (score 2):

When you are on a taxonomy archive (`is_tax()` is `true`) `queried_object` is populated in this way (example from my site):

```
public 'queried_object' =>
object(stdClass)[163]
public 'term_id' => int 2
public 'name' => string 'Puglia' (length=6)
public 'slug' => string 'puglia' (length=6)
public 'term_group' => int 0
public 'term_taxonomy_id' => int 7
public 'taxonomy' => string 'region' (length=6)
public 'description' => string 'Bari, Brindisi, Lecce, Taranto, Foggia' (length=38)
public 'parent' => int 0
public 'count' => int 1
public 'filter' => string 'raw' (length=3)
public 'queried_object_id' => int 2
```

So you directly get both name and description. The code you can use is:

```
<?php 
    $current_term_name = $wp_query->queried_object->name;
    $current_term_description = $wp_query->queried_object->description;
?>

<hgroup class="section-heading wrapper">
    <h1><?php echo $current_term_name; ?></h1>
    <h3><?php echo $current_term_description; ?></h3>
</hgroup>
```

Comment: Is this a guess or a definitive solution? If the latter, you might want to wrap it in a more detailed description (maybe provide a link to the relevant part of the `WP_Query` source or to its documentation. If the earlier, it would be a better fit for a comment, rather than an answer.

Comment: This is a solution, I edited it to better explain the code. This was my first post.

Comment: +1, this became a quality answer. Note that "Try this" is almost never a good way to introduce a solution. Now, with context I can most certainly upvote this.

Answer (score 1):

`$wp_query->queried_object->ID` has several potential points of failure:

- Your query may not be dealing with a `WP_Post` object.  The `queried_object` [can also reference a taxonomy in some circumstances](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object).
- Your query may not have actually identified any results.  Your `queried_object` could be null, and thus you're asking for a property on an nonexistent object.
- You could be using `$wp_query` in code that does not have a reference to that global.  If you determine that `$wp_query` itself is null, you should add

  ```
  global $wp_query;
  ```

  ... somewhere above your code.