# Problem with WordPress 4.0 and $wp_query

Tags: wp-query

On my website I have a logo area that is controlled by a function that determines which page the user is on and loads the specific content depending on the `$page_id` value.

Since WordPress 4.0 there are parts of my site that don't work correctly.

> Notice: Undefined property: WP_Query::$queried_object in
>   /myhost/mysite.com/html/wp-includes/query.php on line 3946

My functions file has this function call in it, which I believe is throwing it off. This is the call that is causing an issue:

```
$page_id = (isset($wp_query->queried_object_id)) ? $wp_query->queried_object_id : false; $parent_id = isset($wp_query->queried_object->post_parent) ? $wp_query->queried_object->post_parent : false;
```

I tried using `$wp_query->queried_object->ID` instead of `$wp_query->queried_object_id` but didn't make a difference.

Could someone out there shed some light on this issue?

I believe this happened since the WordPress 4.0 update and some other functions with the `$wp_query` call have the same error message.

Anyone out there know what could be wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Which parts or your site are you getting this error? Posts? Pages? Post Type archives? Home? The answer can make a different.

Comment: Duplicated: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/60297/wp-query-queried-object-id-throws-warning-undefined-property

Comment: Yep, same issue, same solution. Use the $wp_query->get_queried_object_id() function call to get the value instead of trying to access it directly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got it to work using...
$page_id = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();

I just want to make sure that it doesn't mess with any code. I know that the isset is checking to see if the queried_object_id exists and then if it does do the $wp_query->queried_object_id and if not shoot back false. 
How would I rewrite this variable call to include the isset check? Would it be..
$page_id = (isset($wp_query->get_queried_object_id();)) ? ($wp_query->get_queried_object_id();) : false;

Or would this not be correctly formatted?